# awk to match, merge two files while modifying column input and adding an extra column to the output file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, merge

I would like to merge 2 files and assign it to a new file while adding a new non-existing column using preferably awk in unix:

File 1: VDR.txt doesn't have a header, is space separated and looks like this:

```
chr12-45000000-50000000 --- rs192072617 48225416 0.000 0.270 0.999 0 -1 -1 -1
chr12-45000000-50000000 --- rs181728325 48225429 0.000 0.144 1.000 0 -1 -1 -1
chr12-45000000-50000000 --- rs187216594 48225500 0.000 0.007 1.000 0 -1 -1 -1
```

File 2: METAL1.tbl has a header, is tab separated and looks like this:

```
MarkerName      Allele1 Allele2 Weight  Zscore  P-value Direction       HetISq  HetChiSq        HetDf   HetPVal
rs192072617       a       g       2887.00 1.579   0.1143  ++      0.0     0.032   1       0.8579
rs7929618       c       g       2887.00 -1.416  0.1568  -+      47.4    1.899   1       0.1681
rs181728325      t       c       2887.00 1.469   0.1419  ++      73.9    3.830   1       0.05033
rs7190157       a       c       2887.00 1.952   0.05088 +-      72.7    3.669   1       0.05542
rs12364336      a       g       2887.00 -1.503  0.1328  -+      69.8    3.306   1       0.06902
rs187216594       t       c       2887.00 -0.082  0.9349  +-      74.8    3.964   1       0.04649
rs12562373      a       g       2887.00 -0.290  0.7717  -+      0.0     0.150   1       0.6984
```

Files have unequal number of lines, first file (VDR.txt) is much shorter than the second file (METAL1.tbl).

I want to:

1. Merge these files by the 3rd column of the first file (VDR.txt) and the 1st column of the second file (METAL1.tbl).
2. Keep only the columns 1, 2, 3 and 4 from first file (VDR.txt) and all columns from the second file (METAL1.tbl).
3. Keep only the characters before the first dash `"-"` from the 1st column of the first file (VDR.txt)
4. Add a new column to the output file that repeats a certain character string (e.g. "VDR")
5. Output file doesn't have to have a header, but if that's necessary it would be nice to have it as given below.

So I would like to have an output file (output.txt) that looks like this at the end:

```
gene    MarkerName  chr BP  impute  Allele1 Allele2 Weight  Zscore  P-value Direction   HetISq  HetChiSq    HetDf   HetPVal
VDR rs192072617 chr12   48225416    --- a   g   2887    1.579   0.1143  ++  0   0.032   1   0.8579
VDR rs181728325 chr12   48225429    --- t   c   2887    1.469   0.1419  ++  73.9    3.83    1   0.05033
VDR rs187216594 chr12   48225500    --- t   c   2887    -0.082  0.9349  +-  74.8    3.964   1   0.04649
```

My attempt to this:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5;next}{print $3, gensub(/-.*/, "", $1), $4, $2, a[$3]}' METAL1.tbl VDR.txt
```

It does get the chr column and the column order the right way but unfortunately only prints the wanted columns from VDR.txt and not the merged file.

I am aware that this is a pretty complex example, any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mel

Comment: So did you make an attempt to solve this? If so, you should share this. Questions in the form of "here are my specs, please code it for me" are generally not well received, but questions in the form of "here is my code, and this is the part I'm having problems with" are.

Comment: How are fields identified in the files? Fixed width? or what are the delimiters?

Comment: I'd recommend reducing your data sample to 4 columns or so (just enough to solve the underlying problem). Do you know about the unix/linux command `join`? If you can work with delimited data (like `|` or tab), you can probably do what you want in 1 line. But I haven't looked carefully at your inputs and outputs (because they are too wide  ;-), so I could be wrong. Good luck.

Comment: You really need to simplify or clarify your bullet (3) _Keep only the characters before the first dash from the 1st column of the first file (VDR.txt) -- before the first dash and not the first 4 to not have the dash with the chromosome numbers less than 10 (e.g. don't want to have chr7- but chr7)._  Your sample data has no `chr7` references, so it isn't clear what that is all about.  Getting `chr12` from the `chr12-45000000-50000000` type names is easy to understand, but do you simply want `chr7` from `chr7-45000000-50000000`?  You've neither demonstrated nor explained this extra wrinkle.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I simplified the bullet 3. Sorry for the confusion, I wanted to write a function that's versatile enough to be used for some other files that will likely have some differences. (But was unfortunately a little lazy to give the proper example)  --- Also Thank you very much for the solution,  worked great and was also pretty fast!

Comment: @shellter thanks for the suggestion but the reason I didn't prefer `join` was that I had to order the files. This would be an easy task for the first file (VDR.txt) but not for the second one (METAL1.tbl) which is a pretty big (~ 600 Mb) file. Sorting METAL1.tbl just kept giving me errors and added more processing time, that's why I preferred awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat > test.awk
NR==FNR {
    sub(/-.*/,"",$1)                                      # remove from 1st dash forward
    a[$3]="VDR" OFS $3 OFS $1 OFS $4 OFS $2               # cols 1-4 of the 1st file
    next                                        
} 
FNR==1 {
    printf "%s", "H0" OFS "H3" OFS "H1" OFS "H4" OFS "H2" # 1st part of header
} 
FNR==1 || $1 in a {                                       # header and matching rows
    print a[$1], $0                                       # print'em
}
$ awk -f test.awk VDR.txt METAL1.tbl
H0      H3      H1      H4      H2      MarkerName      Allele1 Allele2 Weight Zscore   P-value Direction       HetISq  HetChiSq        HetDf   HetPVal
VDR     rs192072617     chr12   48225416        ---     rs192072617     a      g2887.00 1.579   0.1143  ++      0.0     0.032   1       0.8579
VDR     rs181728325     chr12   48225429        ---     rs181728325     t      c2887.00 1.469   0.1419  ++      73.9    3.830   1       0.05033
VDR     rs187216594     chr12   48225500        ---     rs187216594     t      c2887.00 -0.082  0.9349  +-      74.8    3.964   1       0.04649
```

As a one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { sub(/-.*/,"",$1); a[$3]="VDR" OFS $3 OFS $1 OFS $4 OFS $2; next} FNR==1 {printf "%s", "H0" OFS "H3" OFS "H1" OFS "H4" OFS "H2"} FNR==1 || $1 in a {print a[$1], $0}' VDR.txt METAL1.tbl
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, this works great but I was looking for a one-liner like the Jonathan Leffler's solution.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the title line is not needed, it is straight-forward in a single, fairly simple `awk` script:

```
$ awk 'FNR == NR { sub(/-.*/, "", $1); row[$3] = "VDR " $3 " " $1 " " $4 " " $2 }
>      FNR != NR { if ($1 in row) { name = $1; $1 = ""; print row[name] $0 } }' \
>      VDR.txt METAL1.tbl
VDR rs192072617 chr12 48225416 --- a g 2887.00 1.579 0.1143 ++ 0.0 0.032 1 0.8579
VDR rs181728325 chr12 48225429 --- t c 2887.00 1.469 0.1419 ++ 73.9 3.830 1 0.05033
VDR rs187216594 chr12 48225500 --- t c 2887.00 -0.082 0.9349 +- 74.8 3.964 1 0.04649
$
```

The files must be listed in the order shown for it to work.

The `FNR == NR` line processes the first file.  The `sub` eliminates the first dash and everything after it in the first field; the assignment is keyed by the markername in `$3`, and contains the information for the start of the line — the fixed code, the marker name, the reduced chromosome number, the BP and the set of dashes marked 'Impute'.

The `FNR != NR` line processes the other file(s).  When the value in column 1 matches a key in the `row` array, then eliminate the key from the current row (which leaves a blank in situ at the start of `$0`), and then print the value from `row` concatenated with `$0`.

There's no need to treat the heading line specially; the value `MarkerName` won't match any of the actual marker names from the first file, so that line is simply ignored.

Comment: and add `BEGIN {print "header you want"}`

Answer (score 1):

I've sorted the two datafiles to use the `join` command - this affects the order of rows in the output - if that is not desirable I can use another approach

```
export LANG=C
genef=$1
metalf=$2
gene=$(basename $genef .txt)
join -13 -21 <(sort -k3,3 $genef) <(sort -k1,1 $metalf)|
awk -vgene=$gene '
{
  marker=$1
  chr=substr($2, 1, index($2, "-")-1)
  bp=$4
  impute=$3
  printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s", gene, marker, chr, bp, impute)
  for(i=12; i<=NF; ++i)
    printf("\t%s", $i)
  printf("\n")
}
'
```

this is the tab-separated output

```
VDR     rs181728325     chr12   48225429        ---     t       c       2887.00 1.469    0.1419  ++      73.9    3.830   1       0.05033
VDR     rs187216594     chr12   48225500        ---     t       c       2887.00 -0.082   0.9349  +-      74.8    3.964   1       0.04649
VDR     rs192072617     chr12   48225416        ---     a       g       2887.00 1.579    0.1143  ++      0.0     0.032   1       0.8579
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the reason I didn't prefer `join` was that I had to order the files... This would be an easy task for the first file (VDR.txt) but not for the second one (METAL1.tbl) which is a pretty big (~ 600 Mb) file. Sorting METAL1.tbl just kept giving me errors and added more processing time, that's why I was looking for a solution around awk.

Comment: good point - sort of 600MB is pretty fast - but a single pass with awk is always good - what errors do you see with sort?